# What does the first number mean on a wand?

Tags: nethack

Whenever I get a wand and identify it, it says `x:x`. For example, the castle wand I got says `0:1`.

What is the meaning of the first number? (`0` in the example)

I know the second number is the number of charges left.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number on the left is the number of times you've recharged the wand (using say the Platinum Yendorian Express Card, scrolls of charging, etc.) This is useful so that one does not accidentally recharge the wand too many times (which can cause it to blow up).